# How to improve performance on Clickhouse Kafka consumer

Tags: olap, clickhouse

I have a Kafka topic of 9 partitions and even when I use 9 consumers, and set the streaming interval to 1 second, I still don't see the machine's resources putting much effort, CPU is even lower than 10% (for 8 cores, 16GB AMI).

Any other properties I should attempt to modify? thanks in advance.

Comment: First, check the lag on each consumer  (you can use [Kafka Tool](http://kafkatool.com) for this goal) - may be the count of events from Kafka is low and CH ingest them very fast.

Comment: Thx, but as part of a test, I've already inserted hundreds of Millions of events to the topic, prior to starting ingestion from CH

Comment: how many partitions the topic has ?

Comment: @nabongs , 9 partitions and on CH 8 cores instance, still barely scratches the resources on that machine

Answer (score 0):

I found out the source of the issue, the streaming poll timeout and the flush interval.

once I added the following to users.xml and restarted, the ingestion rate increased significantly

```
 <stream_poll_timeout_ms>5000</stream_poll_timeout_ms>
        <stream_flush_interval_ms>1500</stream_flush_interval_ms>
        <max_streams_to_max_threads_ratio>4</max_streams_to_max_threads_ratio>
```